# Rails Display Form Error Below Each Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following form

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= @user.errors.messages[:name] %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to display form error for each field below it instead of everything on the top. Went through [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) but was not able to figure how to do it.

Comment: You can use like this `if @user.errors[:field_name]`..

Comment: that outputs wierd brackets like this ***
["Please enter your Name."] ***

Comment: Give like this `if @user.errors[:field_name].join(",")`

Comment: i just want to remove the brackets and display it

Comment: Yes!It will display without brackets.I checked my self.It displayed just `"Please enter your Name."`

Answer (score 15):

You can write a helper to return error message for any field of any object

In `/app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
def show_errors(object, field_name)
  if object.errors.any?
    if !object.errors.messages[field_name].blank?
      object.errors.messages[field_name].join(", ")
    end
  end
end
```

In view file:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <p class='error'><%= show_errors(@user, :name) %></p>
</div>
```

Comment: object.errors.messages[field_name][0] works  i dont wanna join the errors. that removes the brackets and the "

Comment: object.errors.messages[field_name][0] will display only first error and won't display all the errors of that particular field in case you have multiple errors!

Comment: @Himesh i used this method for showing errors below field.. but what should i do when its nested form.?? how can i show nested attributes errrors..??