# in rails specific Field Can be show error messages in validation ? different feild can different error msg show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
<div class="field form-group">
<% form.label :first_name %>
<%= form.text_field :first_name ,class:"form-control",placeholder:"First_Name" %>
<b><%= @teacher.errors.full_messages.first if @teacher.errors.any? %></b>
```

plz check my code and solve out full_messages.first is a not a right method.

Comment: You want to show all the error message or just a specific message related to that field?

Comment: yes,specific message related to that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `errors.messages` and find the error for that field.

```
<div class="field form-group">
<% form.label :first_name %>
<%= form.text_field :first_name ,class:"form-control",placeholder:"First_Name" %>
<b><%= @teacher.errors.messages[:first_name].join(", ") %></b>
```

There are many [articles](https://human-se.github.io/rails-demos-n-deets-2020/demo-form-errors/) and [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932213/rails-display-form-error-below-each-field) for the same. You can refer to them as well